Stoichiometry problem with copper coin with mass 5.00 g. After some time, the coin is removed and its mass is 6.41 g
A copper coin of mass 5.00 g is immersed in a silver nitrate solution where the reaction proceeds:
Cu + 2AgNO3 → Cu(NO3)2 + 2Ag
After some time, the coin is removed and its mass is 6.41 g. Determine
the percentage composition of copper and silver (by mass) in the final coin.
I would appreciate your help.

This problem is impossible. At the end of the reaction, there is no coin any more. All the copper from the coin is transformed into silver. But this silver is made of fine silver crystals  which fall down to the ground of the solution. So the coin itself disappears, if there is enough silver nitrate available in the solution. Apparently silver nitrate is in excess in the solution, but it is not mentioned. It should be. The final mass ($6.41$ g) is not the mass of the coin. It is probably the mass of the final powder fallen down on the ground of the container

The final mass of metal is $1.41$ g more than the initial coin mass. This $1.41$ g is made of silver coming from the reaction of copper with with silver ions. $2$ mole silver is produced when $1$ mole copper react. So $1.41$ g silver contains $\ce{1.41/107.9 = 13.06 10^{-3}}$ mol. This $13.06$ millimol Ag are produced by the half, or $6.53$ millimole Cu, which weighs $6.53 · 10^{-3} · 63.55 = 0.415$ g. The proportion of copper in the original coin is $\pu{\frac{0.415}{5.00} = 0.083 = 8.3}$ %. So the proportion of silver is $100 - 8.3 = 91.7$%
